# make function detect nonexistent column when specified as df$x

Tags: r

I have functions that operate on a single vector (for example, a column in a data frame). I want users to be able to use `$` to specify the columns that they pass to these functions; for example, I want them to be able to write `myFun(df$x)`, where `df` is a data frame. But in such cases, I want my functions to detect when `x` isn't in `df`. How may I do this?

Here is a minimal illustration of the problem:

```
myFun <- function (x) sum(x)
data(iris)
myFun(iris$Petal.Width)  # returns 180
myFun(iris$XXX)          # returns 0
```

I don't want the last line to return 0. I want it to throw an error message, as `XXX` isn't a column in `iris`. How may I do this?

One way is to run `as.character(match.call())` inside the function. I could then use the parts of the resulting string to determine the name of `df`, and in turn, I could check for the existence of `x`. But this seems like a not–so–robust solution.

It won't suffice to throw an error whenever `x` has length 0: I want to detect whether the vector exists, not whether it has length 0.

I searched for related posts on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find any.

Comment: I think the easiest approach would be to check for `is.null(x)` inside the function and return appropriate error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iris$XXX` returns `NULL` and NULL is passed to `sum`

```
sum(NULL)
#[1] 0
```

Note that either `iris$XXX` or `iris[['XXX']]` returns `NULL` as value.  If we need to get an error either `subset` or `dplyr::select` gives that

```
iris %>% 
   select(XXX)
```

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> ✖ Column `XXX` doesn't exist.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Or with `pull`

```
 iris %>% 
     pull(XXX)
```

> Error: object 'XXX' not found Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where
> the error occurred.

```
subset(iris, select = XXX)
```

> Error in eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame()) :
> object 'XXX' not found
> >

We could make the function to return an error if `NULL` is passed.  Based on the way the function takes arguments, it is taking the value and not any info about the object.

```
myFun <- function (x) {
      stopifnot(!is.null(x))
       sum(x)
    }
```

However, this would be non-specific error because `NULL` values can be passed to the function from other cases as well i.e. consider if the column exists and the value is `NULL`.

If we need to check if the column is valid, then the data and the column name should be passed into

```
myFun2 <- function(data, colnm) {
         stopifnot(exists(colnm, data))
         sum(data[[colnm]])
  }

myFun2(iris, 'XXX')
#Error in myFun2(iris, "XXX") : exists(colnm, data) is not TRUE
```